# Finding a bit pattern in a binary file using Python and memory map

Tags: python-3.x, binaryfiles

I am processing a binary file that is not byte aligned at the start. Shortly in the file there is a 24 bit pattern 0xfaf330 that is a sync marker that marks subsequent byte aligned data.  I am using Python mmap on the file and desire to use Python memoryview once the marker is found to process the remaining part of the file. So, how do I find the 24 bit pattern and then use mmap and memoryview from that point forward?

Comment: Is there are reason why you mmap the file and don't just open and stream it?

Comment: The file is very large and memory mapping helps to manage it.

Comment: Using ``open`` will only buffer a portion of the file at any time. Do you need random access? Your description sounds ideal for stream processing.

Comment: Subsequently, memoryview helps to process the remaining byte aligned data in chunks based on the file format specification.

Comment: The data read is subject to Python's regular garbage collection. Unless you hang on to it, it is reclaimed.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need random access, you can use `open` to stream the file. Using `file.read`, you can get consecutive bytes from the file. If your file were byte-aligned, you could directly search through it:

```
in_stream = open('/dev/urandom', 'rb')
# discard individual bytes until first marker byte
while in_stream.peek(1) != b'\xfa\xf3\x30':
    in_stream.read(1)
# in_stream is now positioned directly after the marker
print(in_stream.tell())
```

By default, `open` uses a [small read buffer but never loads the entire file](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open). You can stream through the file using further `in_stream.read` calls.

Alternatively, you can use the result of `in_stream.tell()` to jump to the correct position in an mmap'ed file.

---

## Searching non-aligned bits

To manage non-byte aligned data, you must sift through bytes manually: bit-shifting allows to inspect sub-ranges of bytes. Note that Python only allows bit-shifting `int`, not `bytes`.

```
>>> pattern = 0xfaf330
>>> bin((pattern << 4) + 0b1011)  # pattern shifted by 4 plus garbage
0b1111101011110011001100001011
```

You can use this to scan a window of bytes:

```
def find_bits(pattern: int, window: int, n: int):
    """Find an n-byte bit pattern in an n+1-byte window and return the offset"""
    for offset in range(8):
        window_slice = (window >> offset) & (2 ** (n*8) -1)
        if pattern == window_slice:
            return offset
    raise IndexError('pattern not in window')
```

You can again use this to scan the file stream:

```
in_stream = open('/dev/urandom', 'rb')
# discard individual bytes until first marker byte
while True:
    try:
        offset = find_bits(
            0xfaf330,
            int.from_bytes(in_stream.peek(3)[:4], 'big'),
            3
        )
    except IndexError:
        in_stream.read(1)
    else:
        break
# in_stream is now positioned directly after the marker
print('byte-offset:', in_stream.tell(), 'bit-offset:', offset)
```

Alternatively, you can use binary representation to literally find the pattern in the window. Note that you have to mind padding of zero bits, so it is about the same work.

---

## Reading non-aligned bits

Once you have the bit-offset, you can read-and-align data from the file. Basically, read one byte more than you need, then shift as needed:

```
def align_read(file, num_bytes: int, bit_offset: int):
    if bit_offset == 0:
        return file.read(num_bytes)
    window = file.peek(num_bytes + 1)[:num_bytes + 1]
    file.read(num_bytes)
    data = (int.from_bytes(window, 'big') >> bit_offset) & (2 ** (num_bytes*8) - 1)
    return data.to_bytes(num_bytes, 'big')
```

Comment: This will not work because the beginning of the file is not byte aligned.  Meaning that I could read several bytes and come to the sync marker but read just a few bits of it. A subsequent read  of one byte would read another misaligned part of the sync marker.  Therefore, the marker could be read and not recognized.  Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @GAF Sorry, missed that one. AFAIK Python does not support a resolution smaller than bytes - neither for open nor ``mmap`` nor other means. You will have to bit-shift each chunk.

Comment: Thanks.  Appreciate the follow up.

Comment: @GAF Added a (working) draft how to handle the shifting to find the offset and re-align data. This is probably worth using Cython if your file is large and you read only small chunks at a time.

Answer (score 0):

MisterMiyagi's answer is a good solution. Another solution uses the [bitstring](https://pythonhosted.org/bitstring/index.html) module.

```
aFile = open(someFilePath, 'rb')
aBinaryStream = bitstring.ConstBitStream(aFile)
aTuple = aBinaryStream.find('0b111110101111001100100000') #the sync marker
```

If found, the position in the file is moved to the found location. Then you can read byte aligned data.

```
aBuffer = aBinaryStream.read('bytes:1024') # to read 1024 bytes
```

Comment: readthedocs for bitstring since pythonhosted link is blank: https://bitstring.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ (can't edit since edit queue is full)